# UIPickerView appears empty

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I have a view with two pickers, and I am using `...viewForRow...` to modify the fonts for the text that appears inside the picker. However, one of my pickers appears empty, but if I scroll through the picker, the values appear in their designated textFields. The other picker appears perfectly fine. I am wondering why one of the picker appears empty?

Note the picker that appears empty has two components. It's a credit card expiration date picker, so has one component for month and one for year.

Here is the code for the `...viewForRow...` method:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UILabel *pickerLabel = (UILabel *)view;

    if (pickerLabel == nil)
    {
        //label size
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 280, 30);

        pickerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        [pickerLabel setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentLeft];
        [pickerLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

        [pickerLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:11.0]];
    }

    if ([pickerView isEqual:pickerExpiration])
    {
        if (component == 0)
        {
            [pickerLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [monthsList objectAtIndex:row]]];
        }
        [pickerLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [yearsList objectAtIndex:row]]];

        return pickerLabel;
    }

    billingAddress = [addresses objectAtIndex:row];
    [pickerLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", billingAddress.addressName, billingAddress.fullAddressText]];
    return pickerLabel;
}
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It was because, the picker has two components and the label, I was making via 'pickerLabel' was too big for a two component picker. So, I had to split the width of the CGRect by two, and it worked.